# Need help creating a new data frame in descending order

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I am trying to create a new data frame from the nycflights13 data in tidyverse but am having some trouble. This is the question:

What 5 days of the year had the highest mean distance when leaving from JFK. Sort in descending order. The data frame should have 5 rows, with 'month', 'day', and 'mean_distance' column observations respectively.

This is what I tried

```
Q4 <- flights %>%

mean(distance) %>%

rename(mean_distance = distance) %>%

arrange(flights, desc(mean_distance)) %>%

select(month, day, mean_distance) %>%

head(5)

Q4
```

The screenshot for number 4 is what it needs to look like:
[image]

Comment: Is this a school work exercise?

Comment: `flights %>% mean(distance)` is not correct dplyr syntax. Typically `mean(distance)` in a frame implies summarizing by group, which if I interpret the assignment correctly would be day of the year. A start of this might be `flights %>% group_by(year, month, day) %>% summarize(mean_dist = mean(distance))`, though you still need to take into account *"leaving from JFK"*, the sort-order, and finding the max five days.

Comment: Thank you @r2evans for your comment, I'm still learning data transformations and forgot  'mean' needs to be with the summarize function. I was able to fix it and run the code through :)

Answer (score 0):

Now the assignment is probably done (if it was an assignment ), this is how I would do it:

```
pacman::p_load(nycflights13, tidyverse)

flights |>
  filter(origin == "JFK") |>
  summarise(mean_distance = mean(distance), .by = c(month, day)) |>
  slice_max(mean_distance, n = 5)
```